# Prevent MediatorLiveData event emit on config change

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-livedata-transformations

In architecture samples , There is an extension of MutableLiveData named [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) which helps us prevent a LiveData from firing on phone rotation or config change.

> This (SingleLiveEvent) avoids a common problem with events: on configuration change
>   (like rotation) an update can be emitted if the observer is active.

But we can't cast MediatorLiveData  to SingleLiveEvent. 
How can we avoid MediatorLiveData emitting on config change?

Comment: Sounds like for this scenario, the observer being called is actually the expected behavior. How else would you reinitialize your view with the current selected index?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't want  question update event to fire on phone rotation. I am using SingleLiveEvent but it seems that using switch along with SingleLiveEvent  prevents it to act as I expect. What should I do instead?

Comment: Honestly, just never use SingleLiveEvent.

Comment: @ EpicPandaForce So what is the best way to handle activity rotation with Livedata?

Comment: You should write your code in such a way that observing it again after rotation wouldn't pose a problem. This rule doesn't apply for Navigation commands, but those shouldn't be described as LiveData anyway.

Answer (score -2):

```
   <activity android:name=".appActivity.video.playVideo.PlayVideoFromUri"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"></activity>
```

issue is Activity recrate on orientation change just add above lines in mainfest file.

Comment: see this article-https://proandroiddev.com/singleliveevent-to-help-you-work-with-livedata-and-events-5ac519989c70

Comment: I have used SingleLiveEvent   , it is in the code snippet I posted    : var _question = SingleLiveEvent<Question>() ,     but it seems SingleLIveEvent is not working well with transformation switchmap